# Sharepoint Jquery - can i make a script run after you close the 'Edit Properties' window on a list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I want to run my list item update script when the user clicks the 'Save' button on the Edit Properties window, in my case this is to update a Hyperlink or Image field called 'Stage'  whenever the user modifies another field called 'Request Status'... also, anyway to get the ID of the item that was just edited or refer to it?

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm really stumped with this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been spending hours trying to and can't find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out! See my post here with the answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164192/how-can-i-run-javascript-after-saving-sharepoint-list-item-properties-from-editf/164194#164194

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! You need to use dialogReturnValueCallback which executes a function after the EditForm window closes.

Go here for details on answer:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/sharepoint-modal-help-pass-value-back-to-parent-when-closing

Here is the appropriate code from that link:

//you create the Modal dialog like so...

//Dialog Opening function OpenDialog() { var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions(); options.url = '/_layouts/mySolution/myPage.aspx'; options.width = 500; options.height = 400; options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback); SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); }

//and then make the return function like this...

// Dialog callback function CloseCallback(result, target) { if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) { // Run OK Code // To be consistent with the below... this.dataArray = target.split("^"); var startDate = new Date(this.dataArray[1]); // Note that I use this.dataArray to allow the object to be accessed throughout the code } if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) { // Run Cancel Code } }